# Buenas, no puedo imprimir este echo

Tags: php, mysql, select

echo "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = '$user' OR clave = '$clave'";

solamente me recarga el navegador y al momento de hacer click en "crear cuenta" borra todos los campos en el formulario y no imprime el echo

Comment: si es para ver una prueba, añade al final un `die();` para que se detenga la ejecucion en ese punto.

Comment: Estas haciendo un submit de la página por eso se borra el formulario. cheuqea  en la base que el usuario haya sido creado.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya pude solucionar el error